# Full outer join: sum per date

Tags: sql, date, join, sum

I have two tables: `orders(id, date, qty) A` and `sales(id, date, qty) B`.

I want to know the total orders and sales quantity per day (I may have none or many orders and sales on the same day).

Results should look like this: `A.day1 A.qty B.day1 B.qty`.

I tried a full outer join but totals per day double.

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some real [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Do a UNION ALL instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood what you want, you are on the right lines with Full join:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(o.OrderDate,s.SaleDate),
        o.Total AS TotalOrders,
        s.Total AS TotalSales
FROM    (
            SELECT  OrderDate,
                    SUM(Qty) AS Total
            FROM    Orders
            GROUP BY OrderDate
        ) o
        FULL JOIN (
                    SELECT  SaleDate,
                            SUM(Qty) AS Total
                    FROM    Sales
                    GROUP BY SaleDate
                  ) s
            ON o.OrderDate = s.SaleDate
```

I have renamed some of your column names (date is not a good name as it is a reserved)

Also, your DBMS isn't specified. The above is SQL Server. If you are using MySQL you will need to substitute `ISNULL` for `IFNULL`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I am using MS SQL. Still, I dont understand why I should group first and then join...